# Node.js for loop, event loop, asynchronous resolution

Tags: node.js

Recently I came across code that makes me wonder about how Node.js engine works. Specifically in regards to event loop, for loop, and asynchronous processing. For example:

```
const x = 100000000; // or some stupendously large number 

for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  asyncCall(callback); 
}

const callback = () => {
  console.log("done one");
}
```

Let's say asyncCall takes anywhere from 1ms to 100ms. Is there a possibility that console.log("done one") will be called before the for loop finishes?

To try to find my own answer, I've read this article: https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5. But I'm not sure if there is a case where the call stack will be empty in the middle of the for loop so that the event loop puts the callback in between asyncCall calls?

Comment: If I understand how the event loop works correctly, I would say no, a `for` loop is CPU-bound and as such will run to completion before any callbacks are run.

Comment: Of course it could; it's async.

Comment: @James Depends entirely on the engine's implementation. There's no guarantee the loop will finish first. (Or which async's callback will run first, etc. etc.) You *shouldn't* run tight loops like this, but it's not *guaranteed* to block. Wouldn't surprise me if it *did* in many cases, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton as I said, it is my understanding that it *will* guarentee that code executing in the current context will finish before any new code (i.e. callbacks) will run. The async (presumably IO-bound) code could finish immediately for arguments  sake but the callback won't run until ALL CPU-bound code currently executing has finished. Im not really in a position to go digging right now to back up that understanding but that's generally how I've understood the event loop.

Comment: @James You'd need to show me something in the language spec that makes that a requirement, otherwise I probably won't believe it's inherent to the language and not the implementation. I'm not saying NodeJS or [insert some implementation here] won't behave that way. (Although my go-to multi-threaded JS runtime I don't think would handle this automatically either, can't tell.)

Comment: Guys, [here's](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/how-node-and-javascript-handle-asynchronous-functions-7feb9fc8a610) a good article that reiterates my point about call order - in a nut shell, the current executing function takes priority order before any callbacks run.

Comment: @James Thanks for the article. Just read through it. So in my case, the whole 'function' which is the code block will run first before running anything in the callback queue. That makes sense.

Comment: @Vincent yeah that's how I've always understood it to be, when async code runs any callbacks are placed into a queue (a different queue than the callstack), and the callstack gets priority, and given the current function is on the callstack it *has* to finish before any other code runs.